# Use Force Click to open link in a new tab in Safari?

Tags: safari, trackpad

I know it's possible to open a link a new tab by holding  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  when clicking a link. However, I think it would be great if I could simply use Force Touch for this - then my hands wouldn't have to leave the trackpad at all.

I have [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) installed, but that program lacks a 'single-finger Force Click anywhere on the trackpad' trigger. Is there another workaround to achieve the desired effect, e.g. using AppleScript?

I'm on a 15" tMBP, should that be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

BetterTouchTool does work. Add a Safari specific Trackpad gesture. add Force touch and assign keyboard shortcut.

I used Chrome, and assigned CMD - SHIFT - ENTER to force touch. Worked like a charm.